# Анимация контента разметки при появвлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, анимация, android-layout, клавиатура

Есть активити для ввода логина и пароля, на которой по центру находится блок с двумя полями ввода. При установлении фокуса в любое поле всплывает клавиатура, которая сдвигает блок выше над собой (параметр `adjustResize` выставлен), но происходит это резко, без анимации. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли выставить анимацию для данного процесса?

PS. атрибут `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` в разметке выставлять пробовал - не помогает